# Power-BI (online) odata-refresh not working

Tags: odata, powerbi

I'm trying to import a custom Odata-Feed in Power-BI.
It works like a charm in the Desktop-Version but when I upload the .pbix file and attempt to refresh the dataset, I get this error: "`None of the instances under the Data Management Gateway (PBIPersonalGateway) is registered.`". This happens both for on-demand as well as schedules refreshes.
I also tried implementing basic-auth in my Odata-Feed and logging in from PowerBi with the same result.
What exactly should I register and where?
Edit: The on-demand refresh does work once or twice before breaking, so PBI can, in principal, access the Odata-feed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data feed accessible on the public internet?  Power BI service will need to connect to it directly.  If it's not on the public internet, you can look to use the Personal Gateway to enable access to the data.

https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/649846-power-bi-personal-gateway

Comment: Yes, the data-feed is accessible to the public. Its hosted on sub-domain on a private server. Also, occasionally the on-demand refresh does actually work, but only once or twice, after which I get the aforementioned error-message and only deleting the Dataset in PBI and reuploading the .pbix file "fixes" the problem. The automatic refresh has so far never worked for me.